# How to quick compare large data textbox's one by one?

Tags: c#

I'm using a simple loop but it's slow. Please offer me a faster method??. By the way, textbox show in below image has a large size.

[image]

Simple loop:

```
String a = textBox1.Text;
String b = textBox2.Text;

string[] titles1 = a.Split(new[] { ';', '\t', '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string[] titles2 = b.Split(new[] { ';', '\t', '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (string title in titles1)
{
    foreach (string title2 in titles2)
    {
        if (title == title2)
        {
            textBox3.Text = title + textBox3.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to find duplicate values or unique values from both the textboxes? Please provide specific details.

Comment: Yes, I want to get duplicate values ​​in two textboxes.

Comment: Loops are faster way to achieve this. If you want to shorten your code. Try this to get duplicates `string[] same = titles1.Intersect(titles2).ToArray();`

Comment: I think Intersect function use only c# console app. is not it?

Comment: You can use it in any .net app.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linq:

```
var duplicates = titles1.Distinct().Concat(titles2.Distinct()).GroupBy(title => title).Where(possibleDuplicates => possibleDuplicates.Skip(1).Any()).Select(duplicate => duplicate.First());
```

You need to do a Distinct() on the title in case there are duplicates in the textboxes.

An alternative would be to use a lookup based method and iterate over both lists:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach(var item in titles1.Concat(titles2))
{
    if(!dict.Contains(item)
    {
        dict.Add(item, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        dict[item]++;
    }
}
```

You could even use a concurrent dictionary and... so many possibilities...

Comment: thank you. I'm to take not the same value use this method?? var duplicates = titles1.Distinct().Concat(titles2.Distinct()).GroupBy(title => title).Where(possibleDuplicates => possibleDuplicates.Skip(1).Any()).Select(duplicate => duplicate.First());

Answer (score 0):

Or you yould make use of your multi cpu computer.
first insert all items of your first list into an sorted array to make lookup as fast as possible

```
var sortedTitles1 = new SortedSet<string>(titles1);
```

and then you test your second list in multiple threads against this first list

```
var duplicates = titles2.AsParallel().Where(t => sortedTitles1.Contains(t)).ToList();
```